# Upgrade from Web 8.5 to Sites 9, is DXA update from 1.8 needed?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, sites-9, dxa-1.8

Our customer wants to upgrade from SDL Web 8.5 to SDL Tridion Sites 9.0. We are currently running the DXA 1.8 Java version.

My question is: Can we upgrade to SDL Tridion Sites 9.0 and keep running with DXA 1.8 in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. See the [following blog](https://www.exlrt.com/blog/content-mashups-dxa-2-1) (near the end), or the [official documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-445ED96D-A503-4022-9CEA-160DA3658586).

Sites 9.0 (or rather Content Delivery 11.0.0) is compatible with DXA 1.8, however you won't be able to use the new features introduced, for example content mashups.